# There is a square that vertices are (0,0) (0,2) (2,0) (2,2)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, coordinate-systems, locus

A point P satisfies following condition

: The straight line passing through P and dividing the area of the square  by 1:3 does not exist.

Can we know the locus of P and the area of the locus ?

I think it has to do with logarithm function..

Comment: I revised tags since original post was insufficient in explanation. I think this is duplicate but I can expect sufficient tags can attract more people.

Comment: You should be able to edit the tags on the original.  If you hover to the right of the tags an edit tags button should appear.